# Deviding timeconsuming tasks efficiently across agents

Tags: algorithms

Maybe there's a concept for this problem:

> Suppose 3 Bankrobbers, Alice, Bob and Carl want to heist a bank, and
>   the bank has 10 vaults. The Vaults are of different difficulty. Let
>   those difficultys be reperesented by the time $t_i$ to open them, so for
>   example: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] for the ten vaults. Also, traveling
>   from one vault to another vault takes no time and any vault can only be opened by one robber.

Now my problem: how to effeciently calculate the fastest possible heist?
Note that the vaulttimes may vary and the robber group may be of a different size.

Is this problem maybe known with a different story?

Anyway, my attempt to this is: every robber always picks an unopened vault that takes the longest time.

But I don't know if this is the fastest solution.

**Edit: as it turns this is the fastest time calculation:**

Sort the vaults by their time, it doesn't matter if from smallest to biggest or vice versa.

Now have the robbers in a  list $(y_1,...,y_i)$ where $y_i$ is the busytime they accumulated so far, y is 0 at the beginning for all robbers.

While the vaultlist has elements:

1. Now always choose the robber with the smallest time and give him
   the last vault of the vault list by adding the vaulttime to his/her
   busytime.
2. Remove the last vault from the list.

The heisttime will now be the highest busytime from our bankrobberlist. so some $y_k$.

Can anyone prove that this yields the fastest heisttime?

Comment: The total time is $55$, if you divide it over the three robbers you have that, at least one will need a time of $19$. This will be the best total time. You can easily find many combinations for the vault-robber assignments that will respect this limit.

Comment: @N74 ok, that will work. But what if the times where [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1000], then obviously the best heisttime will not be vaulttimes devided by robbers, but in this case 1000. (assuming 2 or more robbers)

Comment: Also in my comment the mean time would have been $18.33$, but I needed to round it to 19. The mean value is the target for the combination of vaulttmes, not the final heisttime. If a value is more than the mean, obviously it has to be assigned to a robber and will become the heisttime, as long as there aren't no other values forcing you to a combination that overcome that value.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a counterexample: Consider the following $5$ vaults with times to break them:$8,7,6,4,3$.

If we run your algorithm on these vaults with $2$ robbers and with the vault times in decreasing order we get the following distribution:

First robber: 8, 4, 3

Second robber: 7, 6

But an optimal distribution would be:

First robber: 8, 6

Second robber: 7, 4, 3

Also for increasing order we would get:

First robber: 3, 6, 8

Second robber: 4, 7

You can see that your algorithm does not compute the best heist time for this example.